# Resource Dictionary raises exceptions when calling a method located in MainPage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, resourcedictionary

In a windows phone 7.1 project:

My Resource Dictionary Looks Like This:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ItemsTemplate">
            ...
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        ManipulationStarted="ManipulationStarted" 
                        ManipulationCompleted="ManipulationCompleted">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" FontSize="32" Foreground="#FF3B3B3B"  Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding List.ListName}" FontSize="20" Foreground="DarkMagenta" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The ManipulationStarted() and ManipulationCompleted() function are located into the MainPage.xaml.cs and the DataTemplate is being referenced through MainPage.xaml with the following code:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="ListSelector" 
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsTemplate}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

When i try to add items in the list i get an exception.

If i put the DataTemplate inside MainPage.xaml everything works fine.

I understand that the problem is the function reference but i would like first to know why it is not possible to find the function through the resource dictionary and if there is a proper way to do this or to overcome this problem by any trick.

Comment: App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 150 + 0x5 bytes C#

{"Unspecified error "}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the event wiring. There is no corresponding event handlers at the App level, but there are at the page level I am guessing.

Comment: Didn't spot that, I'd say you got it!

Comment: but isnt the resource dictionary being linked on the "page" like libraries do? i mean like we use the #includes (c) or using on (c#) ??

any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using `x:Key` instead of `x:Name` on the `DataTemplate`?

Comment: doesnt make a difference..i changed it when i was trying to find a way to make this work!